# How to view NFC tag object in raw format

Tags: android, nfc

I read about the Tag object in the NFC basics of Android API guide. I then added this [enter link description here](https://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/wiki/AndroidTutorial) project to my Eclipse environment, and can run it on Samsung Note. I now want to view the Tag object that is created in the code. I have marked the code I have added to the existing code. I am not sure if did it correctly. Is there anyway I can see what is inside of the Tag object I have in the code? I did try adding a breakpoint, and looked at what I have in variables, but I don't see a variable called tag. Here is the code from the source:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // initialize NFC
    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    nfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, this.getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

    // Register Android Beam callback
    nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);
    // Register callback to listen for message-sent success
    nfcAdapter.setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(this, this);
    /***********************************
     * I added this portion of the code myself to view the tag object
     ***************************/
    Intent intent = new Intent(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    intent.putExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG, "");
    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    //************************************************************
    if(getIntent().hasExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        //textView.setText("Hello NFC tag from home screen!");
        textView.setTag(tag);
    };

    printTagId(getIntent());
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by looking into the `Tag`object? The `Tag`object is just a handle that points the NFC service to communicating with the right tag.

Comment: I want to see the structure of the NFC tag. My limited understanding of the NFC API, Methods, and classes is that you can now build different tags. I want to build tags manually in order to understand the structure of the NDEF tags. My goal is complete visibility into what the sensor senses; even if it garbage and meaningless, I want to see it.

Answer (score 0):

The `Tag` object is a handle that points the Android NFC service to communicating with the right tag. It does not contain much information about the tag, other than what communication technologies thwe tag was detected to support and the tags ID (as used during the enumeration or anti-collision phase of the communication protocol). You can get that information using the `getTechList()` method (for the supported communication technologies) and `getId()` method (for the tag's identifier).

Other that that, the `Tag` object itself does not contain any information about the structure or contents of a tag. So there is nothing to "view" in the `Tag` object. In fact it is even a bit more complicated than that:

A contactless token can be either a pure memory card (which provides certain commands to read and write data) or can be a processor smartcard (which contains applications that can be interfaced by smartcard commands). With current standardized (by the NFC Forum) NFC tags, there are four different tag types. They differ in communication protocol and memory layout. One of them can even be based on top of a processor smartcard. Besides those standardized tag types, there also exist several NFC-compatible tag types that also differ in memory layout and communication protocol.

So, if you wan to retrieve the structure and data of a tag, you would need to implement that tag's specific communication protocol (and sometimes you even need to know the exact memory layout).

There is however an exception to that: There exists an abstraction layer for NFC tags: NDEF (NFC Data Exchange Format). Current NFC devices typically implement this abstraction layer for at least the four standardized tag types. If your tag is supported (you can find this by browsing the tag technology list or by simply trying to get an instance with `Ndef.get(tag)`), you can get the tag's NDEF contents by using the methods of an `Ndef` instance for your `Tag` object.

Btw. the `getTag()`/`setTag()` methods of various Android UI elements are completely unrelated to NFC tags. So it does not make much sense to store a tag handle with them.

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to explain this. I'll certainly apply it. Since my last post, I found out about the card emulation support on Android also. I knew that cards and readers use the same standard, ISO-14443. I did not know that Android has an api for cards also, so I was trying to see how I can read a card. Now I have some more information on that front. If you know of any card emulation implementations, tools, or SDK which I can download, please let me know. Again thank you so much for taking the time to put this content together. Happy Holidays.

Comment: I hope I can ask a follow on question about this. What information can I collect if I know nothing about the tag that can potentially come close to my antenna? What I mean is let's say I grab an instance of the NFC adaptor in my app and then introduce a tag to the device. Is there some event log that would tell me about antenna sensing something?

Comment: As I wrote above, without knowning what tag it is, you can at least collect the tag ID and the tags technology list. If it is an NFC FOrum tag (or another supported NDEF compatible tag), you may also be able to collect the NDEF message from the tag. There is no log that automatically collects and store tags, but while your activity is in the foreground, you can use the foreground dispatch system to be notified about the detection of new tags.

Comment: I really appreciate this. Contact and contact less communications are not limited to tags. I wonder what happens if I put the phone next to an object with magnetic field that supports ISO-14443-A? Surely the phones NFC antenna registers something? It may through it out as garbage, but at some level I should be able to see an event about this. Am I wrong?